# Functional equation f(x+1)=f(x)+2x+1

Tags: real-analysis, functions, functional-equations

I took the function $f(x)=x^2$ and noted that $f$ satisfies the following functional equation (from well-known equality $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$):$$f(x+1)=f(x)+2x+1.$$

Here's the question: is there another solution $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for this equation? I tried to prove it myself, but didn't succeed. Could you help, please?

Also I wonder: there is another functional equation for $f(x)=x^2$: $$f(x+y)=f(x)+2xy+f(y).$$
Is it related to the previous one? Can we deduce the second from the first?

**UPD1:** the fist question was answered in the comments. What about the second one?

**UPD2:** the second eqution has others solutions too. For instance, take $f(x)=x^2+ax$, where $a$ is an arbitrary real number. See [Functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)+2xy+f(y)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1457497) .

Comment: For the first question. Hint: Lots of solutions exists. Show that for an arbitrarily defined function $g(x): [0,1 ) \rightarrow R$, we can extend that to a function $f(x) : R \rightarrow R$ such that $g(x) = f(x)$ on $x\in [0, 1)$. $\quad$ Please refrain from asking multiple questions in the same post. You can split them up as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It won't happen again. :)

Comment: Is $f(x)$ continuous?

Comment: The first equation notably has $x^2+c$, for any $c \in \mathbb R$, as solution. When $c \ne 0$, this is not solution of the second equation. The solutions $x^2+ax$ you found for the second equation are not solution of the first equation, when $a \ne 0$. So the two equations are not related.

Comment: If $f(1)=1$, then the second equation implies the first. Otherwise, neither equation implies the other.

Comment: This is equivalent to $f(x+1)-(x+1)^2=f(x)-x^2.$ So $g(x)=f(x)-x^2$ can be any function satisfying $g(x+1)=g(x).$ That is, any function of period $1.$

Comment: Given a $g(x)$ of period $1,$ you get $f(x)=x^2+g(x)$ is an example.  In particular, $g$ any constant function works.